# ContextMenu doesn't change MenuItem.Visibility property according to Binding

Tags: wpf, data-binding, contextmenu

I've created a simple project with MainWindow and Model to show the problem.
My aim is to hide a MenuItem if some ObservableCollection is empty. I managed to create a binding for "Visibility" property with help of Converter.
But the problem is that the state when ContextMenu is opened for the first time is locked and even after changing of the "Items" object which is binded to "Visibility", it doesn't change its state anymore.
It means that if I press RMB before any buttons, only "BBB" MenuItem is displayed. But if I press "Show AAA" button before, "AAA" will be shown in ContextMenu.
I want to make appearing/disappearing of "AAA" MenuItem in control from outside of ContextMenu.

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="TestWpfContextMenu.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:testWpfContextMenu="clr-namespace:TestWpfContextMenu">
    <Window.Resources>
        <testWpfContextMenu:C2VConverter x:Key="Converter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="AAA" Visibility="{Binding Items, Converter={StaticResource Converter}, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            <Separator Visibility="{Binding Items, Converter={StaticResource Converter}, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            <MenuItem Header="BBB"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Window.ContextMenu>
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Show AAA" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <Button Content="Hide AAA" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,35,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

With code-behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;
namespace TestWpfContextMenu
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow(Model model)
        {
            DataContext = model;
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ((Model) DataContext).Show();
        }
        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ((Model)DataContext).Hide();
        }
    }
    public class C2VConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var elements = (IEnumerable )value;
            if (elements == null)
                return Visibility.Collapsed;

            return elements.Cast<object>().Any() ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

and the DataContext aka Model is:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
namespace TestWpfContextMenu
{
    public class Model
    {
        public Model()
        {
            Items = new ObservableCollection<object>();
        }
        public ObservableCollection<object> Items { get; set; }
        public void Show()
        {
            Items.Add(new object());
        }
        public void Hide()
        {
            Items.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You bound the `Visibility` to the `Items` Property of your model. Changes inside your `ObservableCollection` e.g. adding or removing items will not trigger anything in that regard. You would have to listen to the `CollectionChanged` event of the `ObservableCollection`. Additonally since your model doesn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` changes to the `Items` property itself e.g. when you assign it a new `ObservableCollection` wouldn't either be monitored or if they do, WPF created a static reference through a `DependencyPropertyDescriptor` which creates a memory leak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in my comment your binding evaluates only the `Items` property itself.
What you can do is the following in your model:

```
public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public Model()
   {
     Items = new ObservableCollection<object>();
   }

  void Items_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
  {
     this.OnPropertyChanged("Items");
  }

  protected ObservableCollection<object> _Items;
  public ObservableCollection<object> Items
  {
     get
     {
        return this._Items;
     }
     set
     {
        if (this._Items == value)
        {
           return;
        }

        if(this._Items != null)
        {
           this._Items.CollectionChanged -= Items_CollectionChanged;
        }
        this._Items = value;
        this._Items.CollectionChanged += Items_CollectionChanged;
        this.OnPropertyChanged();
     }
  }

  public void Show()
  {
     Items.Add(new object());
  }
  public void Hide()
  {
     Items.Clear();
  }

  #region INPC
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  protected void OnPropertyChanged([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string name = "")
  {
     PropertyChangedEventHandler tmp = this.PropertyChanged;
     if (tmp != null)
     {
        tmp(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
     }
  }

  #endregion
}
```

This will trigger a `PropertyChanged` event when you collection contents change. Maybe someone else can come up with a more elegant solution.